# How to harden finished papercraft?

Tags: paint, paper

Not so long ago I made some paper craft, a mask to be exact. It looks awesome, but it's too soft to wear it, so I'd like to harden it and then paint it. Note that it is a 3D model and it took me about 6-7 hours to make it, so making another from carton is not a good option. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you add a picture of your mask for better understanding how it was made

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add layers of more paper over the current one. For this you can use mixture of white glue and water.

For paper layers you can use toilet paper or kitchen paper. Other kind of paper can be used too.

Probably first you will need to protect the base from deformations if it gets wet when you put the glue on it. This can be done with some kind of acrylic spray or paint spray which becomes water resistant after drying.

Add several layers and let it dry. On the top layer you can achieve smooth surface when you put several layers of:

- glue
- mixture of glue, flour, salt
- gypsum (plaster)

You can test first on something smaller to see how it works for your case

Comment: I was thinking kinda something like this myself, but will additional layers stick to the surface after acrylic spray?

Comment: @GaaRa it depends on the glue you choose. I haven't tested it. I only have made models for which I remove the base after drying the paper. But it was hard base like rubber, plastic or metal.

Comment: Spray one very thin coat of varnish on front if test on similar paper shows it will not soak through.  Then reinforce from the back with gummed tape or glue and paper.